# Retrieve custom object from Mongoose Schema

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of JSON objects in my Mongoose schema. Whenever I do a `.find` on the Model it fails to return the array of objects, instead defaulting to an empty array.

My schema is as follows:

```
orders: [
    {
      type: Object,
      required: false
    }
  ]
```

In the database the orders key is as follows:

```
"orders": [
        {
            "options": [
                {
                    "name": "Blueberries",
                    "optionId": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "Strawberries",
                    "optionId": ""
                }
            ],
            "restaurantId": ""
        }
    ]
```

When I invoke Model.find() if returns an empty array. Any help would be appreciated!